# PyObject Pycharm setup failure in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, gtk3, pygobject

HI I am unable to setup pyobject in my pycharm project. I am getting the below  when I am trying to add PyGObject package in my project error message.

**Pycharm Console Error Message**

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/1f/76533985b054473ef6ab1ba4d9c00d62da502f8b43d3171ae588ec81ae93/PyGObject-3.30.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in /home/ritwik/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.18.0)
Installing collected packages: PyGObject
  Running setup.py install for PyGObject: started
    Running setup.py install for PyGObject: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /home/ritwik/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging/PyGObject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-tlwks9ju/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ritwik/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp/venv/include/site/python3.6/PyGObject:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pygtkcompat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
    copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/repository
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gi/overrides
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    Requested 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0' but version of gobject-introspection is 1.40.0
    Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------

Command "/home/ritwik/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging/PyGObject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-tlwks9ju/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ritwik/PycharmProjects/WeatherApp/venv/include/site/python3.6/PyGObject" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/PyGObject/
```

I tried different solutions but none are working for me .I also tried to navigate to the directory via terminal and use the pip command but I failed.Please let me know what is the solution to this

**Below is the list of libraries already installed in my project**

```
Schemer 0.2.11  0.2.11
certifi 2018.11.29  2018.11.29
chardet 3.0.4   3.0.4
idna    2.8 2.8
inflection  0.3.1   0.3.1
pip 18.1    18.1
pycairo 1.18.0  1.18.0
pymongo 3.7.2   
requests    2.20.1  2.20.1
setuptools  40.6.2  40.6.2
urllib3 1.24.1  1.24.1
```

I am also able to create GTK projects locally in my system but not in pycharm.

Please help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at you error message again, specifically this part:

```
Requested 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0' but version of gobject-introspection is 1.40.0
Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It says you're trying to get a version >= 1.46.0, but the version that exists is 1.40.0. You can't use a version higher than the one that exists. So either you or the thing you're importing is trying to import a version that doesn't exist. I would try to change the version and it should work!

Comment: Thanks for your response.I was using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.When I upgraded it to ubuntu 16.04 LTS  the issue got resolved.